# Password History in Jfrog artifactory

Tags: database, user-interface, passwords, artifactory

I was wondering if there is an already deployed feature in Jfrog Artifactory that stores the user's password history.
I would like to have the ability to reject a password which is the same with some that has been used in the resent past.

One solution that I thought is a custom implementation which will query the password history of a user from the MySql database and search in the reults for the given password.

I am using the 6.3.3 version of Jfrog Artifactory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JFrog Access provides some password policy rules (see [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/ACC/YAML+Configuration+File)). But Artifactory does not persist passwords (or old passwords) due to security considerations.

You might argue such a feature can be implemented with password hashes which is correct, but no such thing is currently implemented - you can always submit a [feature request](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT)

Answer (score 2):

That feature doesn't exist as far as I know in Artifactory today, if you're configuring the users in Artifactory itself. If you're using an external user store (like LDAP), you could set those rules there.